# Drop Marker with 3857 projection in leafletjs

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet, projection

Is it possible in leaflet to drop marker with 3857 projection on map?

I fond a solution where first translate point to 4326 using proj4js and than drop it on map.

```
var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3857');
    var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');
    var p = new Proj4js.Point(-12307.601047734, 6711475.1283642);
    Proj4js.transform(source, dest, p);

  new L.Marker([p.y, p.x], {bounceOnAdd: true}).addTo(map);
```

is there any other way in core leaflet or leaflet plugin to drop marker without using proj4js library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending good time on internet.i'm finally done it.

```
var point = new L.Point(-12307.601047734, 6711475.1283642);
var earthRadius = 6378137;
var latlng = L.Projection.SphericalMercator.unproject(
               point.divideBy(earthRadius));

new L.Marker([latlng.lat, latlng.lng], {bounceOnAdd: true}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

Same code into a reusable function:

`L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject = function (point) { // (Point) -> LatLng
    var earthRadius = 6378137,
        normalizedPoint = point.divideBy(earthRadius);
    return this.projection.unproject(normalizedPoint);
}`

Use it like:

`var latlng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(point);`

Example:

`var point = new L.Point(-12307.601047734, 6711475.1283642);
L.marker(L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(point), {bounceOnAdd: true}).addTo(map);`

Comment: That's an even better answer as you can then use map.options.crs.unproject directly (just like you would if using proj4leaflet) and get into that function directly, thanks for sharing!